# Docker-compose command: file not found

Tags: django, python-3.x, docker-compose

I want to initialize Docker for my  Django project with postreSQL. I followed instrunctions from https://docs.docker.com/compose/django/

I also want to be sure that db runs before web so I use `wait_for_db.sh`. When I try to execute command `docker-compose up`

I see following respond:

```
web_1  | chmod: cannot access 'wait_for_db.sh': No such file or directory
pipingapi_web_1 exited with code 1
```

Before I try to use "docker-compose run", I Change directory to project root. I tried also to write
`$ docker-compose run web django-admin startproject pipingapi .` even though project was created before with venv.
I guess its not exactly about .sh file because when I erase lines reffering to that file, Docker cant find manage.py then (look at command order in docker-compose.yml). I also tried to put `code/` before `wait_for_db.sh` in docker-compose.yml but it did not work.

My project tree:

```
.
L apienv/ 
L docker-compose.yml
L Dockerfile
L manage.py
L project/
L README.md
L requirements.txt
L restapi/
L wait_for_db.sh
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.6
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
COPY requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /code/
RUN apt-get update -q
RUN apt-get install -yq netcat
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:12.3
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/postgresql/data
    env_file:
      - ./.env

  web:
    build: .
    command:
      sh -c "chmod +x wait_for_db.sh
      && ./wait_for_db.sh
      && python manage.py makemigrations
      && python manage.py migrate
      && python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    env_file:
      - ./.env
```

If it matters: I use Docker Toolbox on win 8.1

**EDIT(SOLVED):**
It looked like I was overwritting my tree with "code" directory so I deleted

```
    volumes:
      - .:/code
```

and it works

Comment: why you need wait_for_db.sh? in docker compose you already defined that your django depends on DB. so it won't start before DB is running

Comment: You do need a "wait" script here: the Django application won't start before the database container starts starting, but it will frequently need a minute or so to finish starting, and the application can try to connect before then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looked like I was overwritting my tree with "code" directory so I deleted

```
    volumes:
      - .:/code
```

and it works

Answer (score 0):

As the image building stage is complete, you could drop into the docker image and interactively run the commands you are trying to fix.

That should give you some hints

```
docker run -it web_1 bash
```

My guess is, as you are setting `WORKDIR` before you run the `COPY`, you are probably in the wrong directory.